# Is it possible to restrict flex bar chart y-axis count?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

Is it possible to restrict flex bar chart y-axis count?

I have a very big name coming in my y-axis and i want to reduce or restrict it to 5 characters and on rollover i want to display it in full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the labelFunction of the axis. Check out the examples here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_06.html

You should easily be able to add a mouseOver event listener to put your tool tip on.